# New Sony Vaio S15 HDD clicking sound

Tags: hard-drive, sony-vaio, smart

I have a 3 day old S15 vaio. The performance is ok. No freezing or anything like that.

But from the hdd I hear a clicking sound. Not a continuous sound. Typically I hear it when I am not touching the keyboard, or not using the laptop.

I downloaded HDDScan and checked SMART. The result is:

[image]

Last line (G-shock/Free-fall Event Count) got a warning.

Could you help me to understand the meaning the result of the SMART report?

I found a youtube video with same issue, and sound:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iRsaxUyLMzc

**Update**

Smart results from Acronis

[image]

Comment: As far as I know, G-shock is the force of the shock it's detected a shock (and not the number of times it has been shocked).

Comment: and what is exactly mean?

Comment: That, according to this smart tool, it thinks the hard drive is being bashed (like it has been dropped for example). I suggest you download the Acronis Disk Monitor (free) which is also SMART and compare the results. Can you confirm that this is a laptop? If new, and you've not dropped it, it could have been dropped/bashed in transit to you/the shop (so send it back)!

Comment: yes. new. 3 days old. i download Acronis.

Comment: I found a related information: http://disablehddapm.blogspot.hu/

Comment: Acronis report: http://tinypic.com/r/200fndy/6

Comment: As I said, take it back and not have this issue - even if you get it fixed here, you have no idea if any damage has been done which will only show itself after the warranty runs out!!

Comment: i bring it back. get a new one. Sound still persist

Comment: And what did they person in the shop say? Sounds like the batch may be faulty?

Comment: Nothing. They said sorry :) If you bring back a vaio in 3 days they ask nothing.

Comment: I would take it back again, it sounds like the whole batch could be faulty. Or, speak to Vaio first and get their feedback